# Gathering people for online games

Tags: finding-other-players, nobilis

I am planning to run a game of Nobilis on roll20 but I am having trouble finding people for it. Is there some sort of advertisement technique I can use in order to recruit players for my game?

Comment: I think this might be more closely a duplicate of [Where can I advertise for players for my play-by-post game?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37853). I've added it to the banner on the question, but I've left the “where can I find” question there too. (I'm not entirely convinced it's a duplicate of *either* since there's a distinction between “how to effectively advertise” and “where can I”, but I'm also not sure it isn't.)

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to create a game ad at a gaming site. Myth-weavers.com and giantitp.com are good examples of gaming forum sites where gamers regularly go to find games. They are mainly dedicated to play-by-post, but myth-weavers allows advertisements for any games that use the myth-weavers site or discord server in some way. If you choose to use the myth-weavers site, I would recommend creating a game forum for character creation, ooc discussion and meeting/game coordination.